# Show/Hide two Divs with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i have two div's:

```
         <a href="#" class="component_expand"></a>
        <div class="component_wrapper">

        </div>

         <a href="#" class="component_expand"></a>
        <div class="component_wrapper">

        </div>
```

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".component_wrapper").hide();
    $(".component_expand").show();

    $('.component_expand').click(function(){
    $(".component_wrapper").slideToggle();
    });

  });

  </script>
```

I try every time I click on "component expand" one DIV open. Now open two
I'd be happy with who they help me on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your selector specific, use [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

```
$(this).next().slideToggle();
```

Try:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".component_wrapper").hide(); //You can do this using css rule itself
    $(".component_expand").show().click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T4qL6/)**

Comment: It almost works,
I have another button before the DIV
<a href="#" class="component_expand"></a>
<a href="#" class="component_edit"></a>

Comment: @allpnay Use next ().next ()

Comment: <div>
                <a href="#" class="component_expand"></a>
                <a href="#" class="component_edit"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="component_wrapper">

            </div>

Comment: i need change arrow to up when DIV is open, and arrow down when DIV is cllose

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance of `this` and `.next`

```
$('.component_expand').click(function(){
    $(this).next(".component_wrapper").slideToggle();
});
```